# Probability Contour Plot in R

Tags: r, density-function

How can I make a contour-plot (of a self-defined pdf) which will contain $25\%$ of the mass within? 
I was trying to use `contour` and `filled.contour` to do the same, but they don't make the plot I am interested in.

I have used the following code

```
# defining density of my own
alpha = -0.9
I = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2)
sn = function(y1, y2){
      sndensity = 4*((1-alpha^2)^(1/2))*(mnormt::dmnorm(x = c(((1- alpha^2)^(1/2))*y1, ((1-alpha^2)^(1/2))*y2), varcov = I))*(mnormt::pmnorm(x = c(-alpha*y1, -alpha*y2), varcov = I))
      return(sndensity)}


# making the data-frame at which the contour-plot should be made
z1 = seq(-6, 6, 0.1)
z2 = seq(-6, 6, 0.1)
n = length(z1)
z3 = numeric(0)
for(i in 1:n){
  for(j in 1:n){
  z = sn(z1[i], z2[j])
  z3 = append(z3, z)
  }
}
z3 = matrix(z3, nrow = n)


# contour-plot
require(grDevices)
graphics::filled.contour(z1, z2, z3, nlevels = 20, las = 1, color.palette = rainbow)
contour(z1, z2, z3, las = 1, nlevels = 10, drawlabels = F, method = "flattest", vfont = c("sans serif", "bold"), col = "red", xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-5, 5), lwd = 1.2, las = 1)
```

Kind suggestions shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not seem to run, `filled.contour` complains about the `z` parameter. Note that there are many possible contours that will contain 25% (or whatever proportion) of your data; how do you want to decide which to use? You can [calculate the smallest ellipse covering 25% of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26810092/452096), or you could calculate a [tag:highest-density-region].

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have updated the code. My target is to make a probability contour plot of a bivariate probability density function. That is the smallest curve (not necessarily ellipse) covering $25\%$ of the data-points drawn from the density function. The curve will be an ellipse if the density function is elliptical. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest curve corresponds to the highest density values.  So you can do something like:

```
tmpz <- sort(as.vector(z3), decreasing = TRUE)
tmpz2 <- cumsum(tmpz)
w <- which(tmpz2 > 0.25*tail(tmpz2,1))[1]


contour(z1,z2,z3, levels=tmpz[w],
        drawlabels = FALSE, 
        add=TRUE, col='blue')
```

to add an approximate curve to the previous plot.